# Java treemap only saving the last item inserted

Tags: java, hashmap

I am creating a matrix and using map within a map, however when i was populating the matrix it only gets the last value and the rest is `null`.

**Code:**

```
for(int row = 0; row < this.factorPoints.size(); row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < this.factorPoints.size(); col++) {
        TreeMap<Integer,Double> cell = new TreeMap<>();
        if(col == 0){
            cell.put(col, (double)1);
        }else{
            cell.put(col, Math.pow((double)this.factorPoints.get(row).getX(), col));
        }
        System.out.println("ROW:"+row+"; COL:"+col+";cell:"+cell);
        inverseMatrix.put(row, cell);
    }
}
```

I think it is putting the cell by reference and when i instantiate the cell variable it sets the item that was put in the `inverseMatrix` variable to `null`.

**Console output:**

```
ROW:0; COL:0;cell:{0=1.0}
ROW:0; COL:1;cell:{1=1.0}
ROW:0; COL:2;cell:{2=1.0}
ROW:1; COL:0;cell:{0=1.0}
ROW:1; COL:1;cell:{1=2.0}
ROW:1; COL:2;cell:{2=4.0}
ROW:2; COL:0;cell:{0=1.0}
ROW:2; COL:1;cell:{1=3.0}
ROW:2; COL:2;cell:{2=9.0}
```

Comment: you are creating `cell` inside inner loop : `TreeMap<Integer,Double> cell = new TreeMap<>();` Just move it out

Answer (score 1):

TreeMap initialization should be out of the loops.

In your code, you were creating a new instance of TreeMap, everytime a inner loop iterate so that's why your values was wrong.

**Here is the working code:**

```
TreeMap<Integer,Double> cell = new TreeMap<>();
for(int row = 0; row < this.factorPoints.size(); row++){
    for(int col = 0; col < this.factorPoints.size(); col++){
        if(col == 0){
            cell.put(col, (double)1);
        }else{
            cell.put(col, Math.pow((double)this.factorPoints.get(row).getX(), col));
        }
        System.out.println("ROW:"+row+"; COL:"+col+";cell:"+cell);
        inverseMatrix.put(row, cell);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Map` is local to the inner `for loop` and thus the scope of the `Map`, you declared, will be within that loop. Which means the `Map` won't be available once the `for-loop` has completed its iteration, it will be `abandoned`.

What you are doing is creating a `Map`, storing data, but you are limiting its scope so that you can't access it after the `iteration`. So as **@Rehan Javed** and **@rkosegi** said you declare the `Map` outside the outer loop, so that it will be available even after the `iteration`.